# How to block access via URL an API backend,without blocking it from application?

Tags: c#, iis, https, backend

I would like to block Users to access the content from a Back-End API call, that gets some users (so that if they write the URL, to obstruct the users access), but to be accessible when the Front-End calls the Back-End. I host the application in IIS, I use C# as Back-End and Angular as Front-End.

Comment: When your front-end within the browser (or application) can call it, anyone can call your API by simply looking at the network tab or using fiddler as proxy to inspect the requests. All you can do is using authentication via tokens or cookies to ensure the given user is the user.

Comment: But how can you block the user to see the users from the api get? For example I have a user and he has access to see the JSON with all Users. How can I block this user to have access to all resources that are in the api call?The user should only have access to its own data, not to all users data.

Comment: If you authenticate your user, you can use Roles/Claims to allow or not run some operations. If the user can't execute Operation5, you can response with a forbidden message for that operation.

Comment: The only way to do it us authenticate your user, and ensure that the web API only returns data that that authenticated user can see.

Comment: If you store information about all users in a table that can be read through the API call and each user should see only her data, you have to correctly apply a filter in your backend on your data before you push the response out to the frontend.

Comment: @Oliver correct, but you need to be sure that is the user performing the request and the only way to do that properly is authenticate them.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by including a simple Guid token in the call.

Specify the token in the web.config app settings section.

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ValidToken" value="12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012" />
</appSettings>
```

Then in your API method:

```
public HttpResponseMessage yourcall(string token)
{
  var validToken = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ValidToken"];
  if(validToken != token) return null; //or do something else
  ....
}
```

Edit: Sorry having reread your question, the above might not be suitable, as the call is coming from client side. As Oliver mentioned the information about the call would be visible in the network tab. This is more suitable when the call is less exposed (i.e. between applications).

Comment: I know it is visible in the network tab, but that s what I want to block. The User should not see others Users information.

Comment: If a user is logged in to your system, then you know there user id (make sure this is Guid), then you can call your backend API and send the user id. Even if a user inspects the network tab, and can work out the call being made. They would need to know other users ids. If those IDs are Guids and not publicly available then the information is not exposed.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
public class BasicAuthenticationAttribute : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            string eid = RequestDataProvider.GetValue(HttpContext.Current, TypeOfData.UserName);

            if (actionContext.Request.Headers.Referrer != null)
            {
                Thread.CurrentPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(eid), null);
            }
            else
            {
                actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request
                    .CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Please use proper media to get response.", JsonMediaTypeFormatter.DefaultMediaType);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?